# Center an image in tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to figure out how to center an image (svg) in tailwind css.

```
<Container>
  <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl md:text-center">
    <p className="justify-center">
```

// I have tried using center-content, text-center but get the img left aligned. How can I force it into the center of the container?

```
      <Image src={company.logo} alt={company.name} unoptimized />
        </p>
        <p className="mt-4 text-lg tracking-tight text-slate-700">
            {company.name}   
        </p>
    </div>
</Container>
```

I can get the text for company name centered, but the image is fixed in left alignment with every variation I tried.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because your image element set to `display: block`. If so should be able to use `mx-auto` as a `className` on the Image elem. Or you could set `text-center` on the wrapping `<p>` tag and use the class `inline-block` on the Image.

Answer (score 1):

Your `justify-center` wont work if you haven't included `flex`.By default it display of `block`

```
<Container>
  <div class="mx-auto max-w-2xl md:text-center">
    <p class="flex justify-center">   //  specify flex here
      <image src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OIP.o7c7ftXCLdQDsfE9NkWCvwHaGb&w=268&h=232&c=8&rs=1&qlt=90&o=6&dpr=1.3&pid=3.1&rm=2" alt="{company.name}" unoptimized />
    </p>
    <p class="mt-4 text-4xl tracking-tight text-slate-700">Company Here</p>
  </div>
</Container>
```

Output:

[image]

[Tailwind-css playground link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/FyDuhj5JXC)